# Using both OpenNI and OpenNI2 in the same project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

Is possible to use both in the same project? actually they have different classes.

I want to do that because OpenNI2 has the driver for Microsoft Kinect, but the library PCL (Point Cloud Libraries) doesn't work yet with this version of OpennI, so i should use the previous version in order to do use them.

However, if there is a better way to use the kinect and, at the same time, use a library capables of meshing a cloud of point, it could be very helpful

ps: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, 32bits, c++

cheers, Maurizio.

Answer (score 1):

PCL is going to have OpenNI2 grabber. It is [being developed](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/276) and will be merged soon.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Nicolas Burrus nestk library supports both, OpenNI and OpenNI2 and also has a PCL integration.

You may want to check the [nestk Homepage](http://labs.manctl.com/rgbdemo/index.php/Documentation/Nestk) or [nestk on GitHub](https://github.com/rgbdemo/nestk). Some useful example can be found in the [Wiki](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectUseNestk).